# Cannot read from pipe in separate thread from suspended process

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, pipe

I am trying to create process with CreateProcess in suspended state and the read from it's stdout. For base I took MSDN code.
After creating process I'm going to set Job restrictions(not implemented yet) on the process and then I'm starting reading in separate thread from STDOUT pipe. 
Before thread is initiated I resume suspended process.
In result I'm getting nothing from ReadFile call, it just stops and waits for data to arrive even when the process is finished.
Here is the code

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_RdDup = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hSavedStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

DWORD WINAPI CreateChildProcess(LPVOID param);
void WriteToPipe(void); 
DWORD WINAPI ReadFromPipe(LPVOID param);
void ErrorExit(PTSTR); 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 

    printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe")); 

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation")); 

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

    if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe")); 

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation")); 

    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    //CreateThread(&saAttr,0, CreateChildProcess, &siStartInfo, 0, NULL);
    CreateChildProcess(&siStartInfo);
    ResumeThread(piProcInfo.hThread);

    printf( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n", argv[1]);
    //ReadFromPipe(NULL); 
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(&saAttr,0, ReadFromPipe, &siStartInfo, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);

    printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

    // The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
    // To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 

    return 0; 
} 

DWORD WINAPI CreateChildProcess(LPVOID param)
    // Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{ 
    TCHAR szCmdline[]=TEXT("C:\\GnuWin32\\bin\\ls.exe");

    STARTUPINFO *siStartInfo = (STARTUPINFO*)param;

    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.


    // Create the child process. 

    bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, 
        szCmdline,     // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 
    //If resumethread is here - it works well

   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if ( ! bSuccess ) 
        ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
    else 
    {
        // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
        // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
        // of the child process, for example. 

        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    }
    return 0;
}

void WriteToPipe(void) 

    // Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
    // Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    for (;;) 
    { 
        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if ( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

        bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 
    } 

    // Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

    if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) ) 
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle")); 
} 

DWORD WINAPI ReadFromPipe(LPVOID param) 

    // Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
    // and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
    // Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;) 
    { 
        bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
            dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (! bSuccess ) break; 
    } 
    return 0;
} 

void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction) 

    // Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
    // and exit from the application.
{ 
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

And if I call         ResumeThread(piProcInfo.hThread); just after CreateProcess function - It works well. But I need to keep creation in separate function anyway and call ResumeThread few functions after.
So, I would like to what to do to make program get suspended process's output in separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check return values.

You're trying to call `ResumeThread` on a handle that's already been closed.  If you had checked the return value, you'd have noticed that this function wasn't succeeding, which would have told you what the problem was.

Remove `CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread)` from `CreateChildProcess` and the call to `ResumeThread` will work.

You should probably also be closing `g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr` and `g_hChildStd_IN_Rd` after creating the child process, so that you can tell when the child process exits.